# Ordering the results of a Union all Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that gets data out of two tables, one live and one archived, and using a union all query to join the two, however i need the results to come out in date order how can i achieve this? Here is my query

```
SELECT CustomerAccountNumber,
   CustomerAccountName,
   DateTimeCreated,
   DocumentNo,
   TotalValue
FROM (
    (SELECT SOPOrderReturn.DocumentNo,
            SLCustomerAccount.CustomerAccountNumber,
            SLCustomerAccount.CustomerAccountName,
            SUM(SOPOrderReturnLine.LineTotalValue) AS TotalValue,
            CONVERT(date, SOPOrderReturnLine.DateTimeCreated) AS DateTimeCreated
     FROM SOPOrderReturnLine
     INNER JOIN SOPOrderReturn ON SOPOrderReturnLine.SOPOrderReturnID = SOPOrderReturn.SOPOrderReturnID
     INNER JOIN SLCustomerAccount ON SOPOrderReturn.CustomerID = SLCustomerAccount.SLCustomerAccountID
     WHERE (SOPOrderReturnLine.AnalysisCode1 LIKE 'Angela%')
       AND (SOPOrderReturnLine.DateTimeCreated BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-02-16 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-02-24 23:59:59', 102))
     GROUP BY SOPOrderReturn.DocumentNo,
              SLCustomerAccount.CustomerAccountName,
              SLCustomerAccount.CustomerAccountNumber,
              CONVERT(date, SOPOrderReturnLine.DateTimeCreated),
              SOPOrderReturn.DocumentTypeID
     HAVING (SOPOrderReturn.DocumentTypeID <> '1') )
  UNION ALL
    (SELECT SOPOrderReturnArch.DocumentNo,
            SLCustomerAccount.CustomerAccountNumber,
            SLCustomerAccount.CustomerAccountName,
            SUM(SOPOrderReturnLineArch.LineTotalValue) AS TotalValue,
            CONVERT(date, SOPOrderReturnLineArch.DateTimeCreated) AS DateTimeCreated
     FROM SOPOrderReturnLineArch
     INNER JOIN SOPOrderReturnArch ON SOPOrderReturnLineArch.SOPOrderReturnID = SOPOrderReturnArch.SOPOrderReturnID
     INNER JOIN SLCustomerAccount ON SOPOrderReturnArch.CustomerID = SLCustomerAccount.SLCustomerAccountID
     WHERE (SOPOrderReturnLineArch.AnalysisCode1 LIKE 'Angela%')
       AND (SOPOrderReturnLineArch.DateTimeCreated BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-02-16 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-02-24 23:59:59', 102))
     GROUP BY SOPOrderReturnArch.DocumentNo,
              SLCustomerAccount.CustomerAccountName,
              SLCustomerAccount.CustomerAccountNumber,
              CONVERT(date, SOPOrderReturnLineArch.DateTimeCreated),
              SOPOrderReturnArch.DocumentTypeID
     HAVING (SOPOrderReturnArch.DocumentTypeID <> '1') ) ) x
```

The result of this is such.

```
CustomerAccountNumber   CustomerAccountName DateTimeCreated DocumentNo     TotalValue
4063                       Account Name       16/02/2015    25/08/2538  12/05/1901
10306                      Account Name       16/02/2015    28/08/2538  10/08/1900
2063                       Account Name       16/02/2015    29/08/2538  26/11/1900
169                        Account Name       17/02/2015    10/09/2538  07/01/1902
7335                       Account Name       18/02/2015    02/10/2538  06/02/1900
9159                       Account Name       19/02/2015    11/10/2538  15/07/1901
7578                       Account Name       19/02/2015    13/10/2538  22/10/1900
2144                       Account Name       20/02/2015    02/11/2538  14/12/1900
169                        Account Name       20/02/2015    07/11/2538  22/11/1900
9633                       Account Name       23/02/2015    28/11/2538  21/07/1901
10152                      Account Name       23/02/2015    29/11/2538  23/09/1902
10247                      Account Name       23/02/2015    05/12/2538  11/06/1901
```

So i would want the  DateTimeCreated column to be in date order

Comment: Add  `order by DateTimeCreated` to the end of your query.

Comment: Where ever i try and order it from it gives me errors

Comment: Try adding `ORDER BY 3` at the end

Comment: @TobyLL that worked, What does the 3 mean?

Comment: 3 is the Column ordinal that you want to sort by. It features in [Aaron Bertrand's bad habits to kick series](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal). It would be much more clear to just use `ORDER BY DateTimeCreated` as Gordon suggested. What error do you get when doing this?

Comment: @ TobyLL it is not recommend.once the table is changed (add,delete column) the  Column ordinal also be changed and the query will not work

Answer (score 0):

Make this as a single query by putting all inside brackets() and give it a name and than write order by accordingly

Like:

```
Select * from (Your query)<tableName> order by DateTimeCreated desc
```

Answer (score 0):

do it as function

```
create function funcx
returns table
as return
(SELECT CustomerAccountNumber, ...)

select  * 
from
        dbo.funcx
order by 
        DateTimeCreated
```